# T-SQL Select Some Column About Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select about value some column and other columns equal,

You can show example below,

```
ID      A_Col     B_Col      C_Col       D_Col
1       15        36         1100        1650
2       15        36         1115        1900
3       19        38         1100        1750
4       15        36         900         1925
```

This example A and B columns equal but C or D columns not equal and 2% range different.

So this table output below

```
ID      A_Col     B_Col      C_Col       D_Col
1       15        36         1100        1650
2       15        36         1115        1900
4       15        36         900         1925
```

- 1st and 2nd row's A and B column equal and C_Column difference about %1,3
- 2st and 4th row's A and B column equal and D Column difference about %1,6

So this output true.

How I can create this select query.

Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: what happen if I add data `(5,15,38,1100,1400),(6,15,38,1120,1600),(7,15,31,1300,1610)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours example ( I added some values )

```
declare @T table (ID int, A_Col int,     B_Col int,     C_Col int,       D_Col int )

insert @T
values (1,15,36,1100,1650)
,(2,15,36,1115,1900)
,(3,19,38,1100,1750)
,(4,15,36,900,1925)
,(5,15,36,1900,2925)
,(6,15,36,1900,2930)


select * from @T T
where exists( 
             select 1 from @T 
             where ID <> T.ID
             and D_Col <> T.D_Col
             and C_Col <> T.C_Col
             and A_Col = T.A_Col 
             and B_Col = T.B_Col
             and ( 
                  CONVERT(float,C_Col)/T.C_Col between 0.98 and 1.02
                  or 
                  CONVERT(float,D_Col)/T.D_Col between 0.98 and 1.02)
      )
```

Give us Result

```
(6 row(s) affected)
ID          A_Col       B_Col       C_Col       D_Col
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           15          36          1100        1650
2           15          36          1115        1900
4           15          36          900         1925

(3 row(s) affected)
```

if not required that D and C have to be NOT EQUAL then query should be

```
select * from @T T
    where exists( 
                 select 1 from @T 
                 where ID <> T.ID
                 and A_Col = T.A_Col 
                 and B_Col = T.B_Col
                 and ( 
                      CONVERT(float,C_Col)/T.C_Col between 0.98 and 1.02
                      or 
                      CONVERT(float,D_Col)/T.D_Col between 0.98 and 1.02)
          )
```

and result

```
(6 row(s) affected)
ID          A_Col       B_Col       C_Col       D_Col
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           15          36          1100        1650
2           15          36          1115        1900
4           15          36          900         1925
5           15          36          1900        2925
6           15          36          1900        2930

(5 row(s) affected)
```